# If TRUE in one column, change value in other column

Tags: r

I have a character vector: (shortened version shown)

```
Unit <- c("e10", "e11", "10e10", "10e11")
```

I want to apply the following condition: if the value start with 'e', replace 'e' with '10e' so that the final vector will look something like this:

```
"10e10" "10e11" "10e10" "10e11"
```

I used startsWith() to create a TRUE/FALSE vector:

```
startsWith.e <- startsWith(Unit, "e")
```

This gives TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE.

Lastly, I want to run a for or while loop (or some kind of conditional), so that when startsWith.e is TRUE, values 'e' in Unit are replaced with '10e'.

```
while(startsWith.e){
grep("e", "10e", Unit) }
```

However, I get stuck in an infinite loop and using an if statement says it will only evaluate the first statement (and therefore change all cases because it will evaluate TRUE).

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Using your own method you could solve this without rexex `Unit[startsWith(Unit, "e")] <- paste0("10", Unit[startsWith(Unit, "e")])` or similarly `Unit[substr(Unit, 1, 1) == "e"] <- paste0("10", Unit[substr(Unit, 1, 1) == "e"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` for this.  Match the letter 'e' at the start (`^`) of the string and replace with '10e'

```
sub("^e", "10e", Unit)
#[1] "10e10" "10e11" "10e10" "10e11"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `startsWith` and subsetting, you could do

```
Unit[startsWith(Unit, "e")] <- paste0("10", Unit[startsWith(Unit, "e")])
```

which returns

```
Unit
[1] "10e10" "10e11" "10e10" "10e11"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `for`, like this (but this is longer version of lmo's answer):

```
Unit <- c("e10", "e11", "10e10", "10e11")
startsWith.e <- startsWith(Unit, "e")
for (i in 1:length(Unit)) {
 if (startsWith.e[i]) {
    Unit[i] <- paste0("10", Unit[i])
  }
}
Unit
#> [1] "10e10" "10e11" "10e10" "10e11"
```

Answer (score 0):

(My answer is redundant... @akrun already solved it with sub )

Why not use gsub..?

```
Unit <- c("e10", "e11", "10e10", "10e11")
gsub("^e","10e",Unit)
[1] "10e10" "10e11" "10e10" "10e11"
```